# Getting no value or zero at the first launch of app from specific field of Firebase Database. Help me by suggesting where i am going wrong?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have written code to get the stored value from the firebase database.
But when i launch the app for the first time  (also happen when i close the app,clear app from phone process and launch app again) the values might come as zero/or might be not getting instead of previously stored value in that field.
Actually when i add the stock after the first launch and if i again add stock it works fine.(means oldstock+newstock)but at first launch of app it doesnt get the old value instead of getting value when i add stock first time it replace that value with the old one,and then all thing works fine like get old and add new to old and srtored.Also there is no error or warnings.
So guys i want to solve-out this thing.
Thanks Again for your helps.

Here is my db structure.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wN5z.png)

and here is my code:-

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_stockaddpage);
    btnsbmt =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    btnupdt =(Button)findViewById(R.id.updt_btn);
    stock_rev = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("STOCK").child("FLOWERS").child("ROSE").child("instock");
    stock_rev.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            finstockval2=dataSnapshot.getValue(long.class);

            Toast.makeText(stockaddpageActivity.this, ""+finstockval2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
    btnsbmt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "entered.....", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            spnitm = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.typspn);
            spnname = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.nmspn);

            qtyvalues = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.qtyinpt);
            msrspn = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.measurespn);

            itmtype = spnitm.getSelectedItem().toString();
            itmname = spnname.getSelectedItem().toString();
            stckinpval = qtyvalues.getText().toString();
            convrtdval = Long.parseLong(stckinpval);

            msrval = msrspn.getSelectedItem().toString();

            Log.d("first","in click");

            if (itmtype.equals("Flowers")) {

                Toast.makeText(stockaddpageActivity.this, "entered.....flowers", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                if (itmname.equals("Rose")) {
                    Toast.makeText(stockaddpageActivity.this, "entered.....rose", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    datareff1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("STOCK").child("FLOWERS").child("ROSE").child("instock");
                    datareff2 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("STOCK").child("FLOWERS").child("ROSE").child("History");


                    if (convrtdval != null) {
                        if (msrval.equals("Grams")) {
                            calculatedvalue = convrtdval;
                            fintype = "Flowers";
                            finname = "Rose";
                            finstockval = finstockval2+calculatedvalue;
                            finstockval2=0;
                            finmeasure = "Grams";
                            datareff1.setValue(finstockval);
                            Log.d("in gram","in gram");
                            currentDate =Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
                            tim = currentDate.toString();


                            Toast.makeText(stockaddpageActivity.this, "Grams : Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, dt, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Toast.makeText(stockaddpageActivity.this, tim, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            calculatedvalue = (convrtdval) * 1000;
                            fintype = "Flowers";
                            finname = "Rose";
                            finstockval = finstockval2+calculatedvalue;
                            finstockval=0;
                            finmeasure = "Kilograms";
                            datareff1.setValue(calculatedvalue);
                            Toast.makeText(stockaddpageActivity.this, "KG : Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    }
                }
                if (itmname.equals("Lily")) {
                    Toast.makeText(stockaddpageActivity.this, "entered.....lilly", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    datareff1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("STOCK").child("FLOWERS").child("LILLY").child("instock");
                    datareff2 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("STOCK").child("FLOWERS").child("LILLY").child("History");
                    stock_rev = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("STOCK").child("FLOWERS").child("LILLY").child("instock");
                    stock_rev.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            finstockval3 = dataSnapshot.getValue(Long.class);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });
                    if (convrtdval != null) {
                        if (msrval.equals("Grams")) {
                            calculatedvalue = convrtdval;
                            fintype = "Flowers";
                            finname = "Lilly";
                            finstockval = finstockval3+calculatedvalue;
                            finmeasure = "Grams";
                            datareff1.setValue(finstockval);
                            Log.d("in gram","in gram");
                            currentDate =Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
                            tim = currentDate.toString();


                            Toast.makeText(stockaddpageActivity.this, "Grams : Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, dt, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Toast.makeText(stockaddpageActivity.this, tim, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            calculatedvalue = (convrtdval) * 1000;
                            fintype = "Flowers";
                            finname = "Lilly";
                            finstockval = finstockval3+calculatedvalue;
                            finmeasure = "Kilograms";
                            datareff1.setValue(calculatedvalue);
                            Toast.makeText(stockaddpageActivity.this, "KG : Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    }
                }
            }



        }
    }); 
}
}
```

Comment: Try `finstockval2 = dataSnapshot.getValue(Integer.class);` in `onDataChange` and let me know.

Comment: @ChiragSavsani thanks for suggestion. There were to errors i got. One was made by my friend who set the variable to 0 in that code so i commented it out. And the second one was that i called the datasnapshot changed only once on create so it will work only once when the app start and get the data.(which leads to get fresh data i must have to restart the app)..instead of that i called it twice..oncreate and also in addstock click event so i get updated data on both events.

Comment: It’s a good idea to include code and structures as text, not links and images. To get your Firebase structure, use the Firebase console->Export JSON and copy and paste a snippet of your structure. See [images and links are evil](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)